# Windows 7 Professional Network Sharing Permissions

Tags: windows, file-sharing, network-shares

I want to set up permissions for a share on my PC for other users on my home network (not a domain, which I suspect may be the issue).

When I go to add permissions to a share, I get the following dialog:

[image: Select Users or Groups Dialog]

When I click on locations, I get the following dialog:

I want to give permissions to a user on a computer called `THUNDERLAPTOP`. As you can see in the screenshot below, I am able to connect to the laptop:

[image: Connecting to THUNDERLAPTOP]

However, when I click `Locations...` in the original dialog, I get the following dialog (with no option to select `THUNDERLAPTOP` as a location):

[image: Only option for location available is KEN-PC]

**Is there a way to get `THUNDERLAPTOP` or other devices on the network to show up in this list without creating a Windows domain? I am open to third party software if that is what it takes (I can't afford a Windows Server license to make a domain).**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 7 has "homegroups" that you can use to delegate shares, otherwise you need to have the same account on each computer (i.e. THUNDERLAPTOP needs to have an account on the computer being shared as well as the computer accessing it). Or share with Everyone. Generally a Very Bad Idea(tm)

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/help/videos/sharing-files-with-homegroup

Once your homegroup is set up, right click on the file, click Share with, and pick homegroup (read or read/write)

Comment: Is there a way to specify specific users in the homegroup with read/write access? Basically I want to set up a file server running windows with a private folder for each person (each person has their own computer as well) and a public folder for everybody to use.

Comment: For specifc users, you will need to create an account for each user on your "server" and create matching accounts(same password too) on each "client" computer which will access it, then assign permissions to the users.

Comment: In that case, if a user wants to change their password then will they have to change it on their computer as well as the server for everything to keep working (two total password changes)?

Comment: Correct. In order to access the file, the client has to send credentials to the server, so the server has to have the right information stored.

Comment: Hm. Alternatively you could use "password protected sharing," and just put the users on your "server" computer, then when they access they input the username/password you give them. http://www.home-network-help.com/password-protected-file-sharing-in-windows-7.html